# Use FilterDescriptor for international encodings (chars with accents)

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria, wcf-ria-services

Simple question... I have a service which returns the users and I implemented a [FilterDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422357%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) which calls that service to populate a grid.

The filterdescriptor has the `Contains` operator and it works fine as far as the user's first or last name does not have accents.
If I want to search for the 'Gómez' is my table, I want to be able to just type 'gomez', but that it's not working.

Is there a property or something I'm missing? How can I achieve that?

Comment: The FilterDescriptor just translates it's output to something like myString.ToLower().Contains("inputString".ToLower()) (assuming case insensitivity). How do standard string operators handle accents?

Comment: I believe it depends on the StringComparison enumerator, but will check on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question helped me out... 
[Ignoring accents in SQL Server using LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322441/ignoring-accents-in-sql-server-using-linq-to-sql)

```
ALTER TABLE IDBUsers ALTER COLUMN LastName nvarchar(256) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```