# Ignore acutes in LINQ when using "Contains"

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, full-text-search, string-search

Is it possible in pure LINQ-to-entities to use String's Contains() method without considering the acutes?

Example:

> ```
> table Messages
> ---------------------------
>   MessageId     Body
>      1          Hello John how are you
>      2          Hi Jóhn sup?
>         ...
> ```

I want that this query:

```
var messages = db.Messages.Where(p => p.Body.Contains("John"));
```

Not only returns to me the first message, but the second message too.

If this is not the correct approach (Contains), which one is it?

I´m using SQL Server.

Also, there is a similar but different question here:
[Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

It is different because he is trying to compare two strings ("Equals", or "CompareTo"), ...while I´m trying to use "Contains"

Comment: you're using sql server ?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

Comment: @user1994514  I saw that question and is completly different... "Equals" is different from "Contains"

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes, i will add that to the question with an edit

Comment: @sports so you'd rather look at this one, which is "linq to entities" friendly : look at the field collation part : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8144930/961526

Comment: Thanks @RaphaëlAlthaus, so if someone comes to this post, the answer is to ALTER the column´s "COLLATION" to "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI", so that WHERE queries dont consider caps and accents.

Comment: @sports well, I'd rather say "a collation ending with AI" (not everybody uses SQL_Latin1...), or CI_AI if you also want case insensitivity. (CI = case insensitive, AI = accent insensitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has been in the comments for a while. Here it is as an answer too:

Alter the database collation to one that ends with "_AI" for making it accent insensitive (or "_CI_AI", for making it case insensitive too)